# Ошибка сборки: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

Tags: debian, gcc

Использую Debian 11, GCC 10
При сборки CGMiner выдает ошибку

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz.
```

Если собирать на `Ubuntu 14.04, GCC 4.8`, то данной ошибки нет.
Какой библиотеки или пакета не хватает?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcrypto++-dev`.

Проблема в том, что компоновщик ищет **libmagic.so**, но у вас есть только libmagic.so.1.

[Быстрый хак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library) — создать символическую ссылку **libmagic.so.1** на **libmagic.so**.